# AWS Lambda - what is the minimal security group for talking to AWS API?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-route53

I have a lambda that needs to talk to a few AWS APIs.
It accesses the EC2 and Route53 APIs in order to get the ip address for an instance and update a Route53 recordset.

The lambda runs in a private VPC in ap-southeast-2.  In order for the API calls to work, I have to add the following egress rule to the Lambda's security group:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "https-egress-lambda-to-all" {
  type = "egress"
  from_port = 443
  to_port = 443
  protocol = "tcp"
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.lambda-sg.id}"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}
```

At the moment this rule says `"allow this lambda to talk to anything on the internet via port 443"`.  I'd like to narrow that statement to `"allow this lambda to talk to the AWS API servers only"`.

I thought a VPC endpoint might be the way this is supposed to be done, but apparently that works only for S3.

**Is there any way to lock down a security group's egress rules to allow access only to the AWS *API* servers?**

Answer (score 0):

AWS publishes the IP ranges that it uses for the services. You can set up rules to allow only these IP address ranges. As they change often, you probably want to automate that. Details are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html

Comment: But of those IP addresses listed, which ones are the ones responsible for servicing API requests?  Doesn't seem worth the effort to lock it down to just things running on AWS, that's half the internet these days anyway.  Might as well just leave it open (which is where I was leaning in the first place, but I wanted to see if I was missing something obvious).